# Magento - Warning message after compilation

Tags: magento

After compiling in Magento back-end/admin interface, I get the following warning when going to back-end menu item Sales -> Orders (site name has been substituted for "...":

> Warning:
>   include(/home/.../public_html/includes/src/Klarna_KlarnaPaymentModule_Model_Order_status.php)
>   [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>   in /home/.../public_html/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 93.

This Warning page shows instead of the expected/normal contents of the page. When compilation is disabled I do not get this warning.

Here is code from Varien_Autoload which includes the mentioned line 93 (the line starting with return_include):

```
/**
 * Load class source code
 *
 * @param string $class
 */
public function autoload($class)
{
    if ($this->_collectClasses) {
        $this->_arrLoadedClasses[self::$_scope][] = $class;
    }
    if ($this->_isIncludePathDefined) {
        $classFile =  COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $class;
    } else {
        $classFile = str_replace(' ', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $class)));
    }
    $classFile.= '.php';
    //echo $classFile;die();
    return include $classFile;
}
```

and here is the contents of the file class Klarna_KlarnaPaymentModule_Model_Order_Status.php:

class Klarna_KlarnaPaymentModule_Model_Order_Status
    extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Status
{

```
const ACCEPTED = "klarna_accepted";
const PENDING = "klarna_pending";
const DENIED = "klarna_denied";

/**
 * Get status labels per store and hiding Klarna status for customers
 *
 * @return array Array of status labels
 */
public function getStoreLabels()
{
    $status = $this->getStatus();
    if ($status !== self::ACCEPTED
        && $status !== self::PENDING
        && $status !== self::DENIED
    ) {
        return parent::getStoreLabels();
    }

    $labels = array();
    $processing = Mage::getModel('sales/order_status')
        ->load(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING);

    foreach (Mage::app()->getStores() as $store) {
        $storeId = $store->getId();
        $labels[$storeId] = $processing->getStoreLabel($storeId);
    }

    return $labels;
}
```

}

I would very much appreciate which steps to take to fix this.

Comment: The problem in the possible duplicate you are refering to was caused by incorrect folder permissions. This is not the case here, as all folders have been set to 755 and all files to 644.

Comment: Either way, Stack Overflow requires substantial research on a topic before asking for help.  If the answer to another questions did not work for you, explain why and you need to provide code or else no person can possibly help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: I am just a newbie to this, and do not have extensive programming experience. That is why I am asking for advice here. I think I have answered why the solution to the suggested duplicate was not relevant (folder permissions), and I also did think that I submitted code.

Comment: You will need to provide the code that gives you this error and try http://google.com

Comment: I have edited the post, including the code from the two files. I have of course tried Google before I posted here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Perfect.  This would be a much better suited question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Module is probably incompatible with the compiler. Its a common problem.

Comment: The problem has been solved. There was a mistype in the file app/code/community/Klarna/KlarnaPaymentModule/etc/config.xml where on line 64 this line:<order_status>Klarna_KlarnaPaymentModule_Model_Order_status</order_status> should read: <order_status>Klarna_KlarnaPaymentModule_Model_Order_Status</order_status> (notice the difference in lower/upper case). Sloppy programming from the Magento extension developer ;)